# Access host VPN from inside a docker-compose container (laradock)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vpn, laradock

I'm using [laradock](https://laradock.io/) as a local development environment. I'm writing an app that needs to access a secure database only accessible via VPN. This works great on my primary host (running MacOS 10.14) and I can access the database directly using it's vpn network ip (10.xx.x.xxx). Perfect.

I (incorrectly) assumed that the Docker environment would also be able to access this, but it cannot. The docker-compose.yml file I'm using [is untouched from the laradock default](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/master/docker-compose.yml), but specifically the boxes that need access are `php-fpm` and `workspace`.

Comment: Have you tried restarting docker after connecting to the VPN? The embedded VM may not have picked up the routing changes.

Comment: You need to export HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY as environment variables to access it inside the containers

Comment: Assuming you don't have subnet clashes between docker's internal and your VPN internals... did you try some of these suggestions? https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2820

Comment: I have tried restarting docker – to no avail.

Comment: If you have in your host the vpn configured the only thing you need is define in your docker-compose **network_mode: host**
Example:
`version: '3'

services:
 
  database:
    image: postgres:10
    container_name: postgres10
    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - 5432:5432`

Comment: Possibly a duplicate or similar problem to another question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69228372/docker-compose-route-traffic-through-vpn-except-for-connections-to-other-servic
Unfortunately, none of the solutions worked for me. I had this problem using MacOs with an OpenVPN client. Here is my answer to how I managed to solve the issue - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77688495/3161980

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have added a new host in **nginx and workspace**

For those who utilizing a docker-compose file, try adding additional host properties to your Docker-compose.yml

Try:

extra_hosts:
- "url.company.net:192.xx.xx.xx"

This will add a entry to /etc/hosts file