# docker-compose: route traffic through vpn except for connections to other services

Tags: docker-compose, vpn, docker-network

Consider this docker-compose configuration:

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    depends_on:
      - db
      - vpn
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
  db:
    image: postgres
  vpn:
    build: ./vpn
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
```

### Description

- The `app` is accessed from the docker host via http://localhost:3001.
- The `app` needs to connect to a postgres `db`, which is the second container.
- Also, the `app` needs to connect to an api, which is only available though a vpn. This is why a third container, `vpn`, establishes the required vpn connection.

### Goal

The `app` container should should be able to reach the other services within this docker-compose environment, i.e. the `db`, and route the rest of its traffic through the `vpn` container, such that it can access the api behind the vpn tunnel.

### What I've tried

- I have tried to set the `network_mode` of the `app`:

  ```yaml
  services:
    app:
      network_mode: "service:vpn"
  ```

  This routes all traffic of the `app` container through the `vpn`. With this, I can reach the api behind the vpn tunnel from the `app` container. But this is not compatible with `ports: - "3001:3000"`. Also, the `db` container cannot be reached from the `app` anymore: `ping: bad address 'db'`.
- I also have tried to link the `db` container from the `vpn` container, hoping that this would make the `db` service available to the `app`.

  ```yaml
  services:
    app:
      network_mode: "service:vpn"
    vpn:
      links:
        - db
  ```

  But still `db` cannot be found by `app`.
- If I link the `db` container from the `vpn` container but do *not* establish the vpn connection within the `vpn` container, the `db` container *can* be reached from the `app`.
- And I've experimented with adding `127.0.0.1 db` to the `/etc/hosts` of the `app` container, vaguely hoping that I could reach the `db` port directly. But this also does not work.

Does anyone have a clue how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally found a solution, but it required three steps:

### Step 1: `network_mode: service`

In order to route all traffic of the `app` container through the `vpn`, set `network_mode` on the `app` container:

```yaml
services:
  app:
    network_mode: "service:vpn"
```

### Step 2: DNS servers

In order to resolve both the host names behind the vpn tunnel as well as the local docker services, the `vpn` container needs to talk to both DNS servers: the DNS server behind the tunnel as well as the docker-compose DNS server.

The docker-compose DNS server is always `127.0.0.11` as far as I understood.

To find out the remote DNS server behind the tunnel, establish the tunnel and then run `cat /etc/resolv.conf`. This will list the DNS server behind the tunnel in the line commented with "by strongSwan".

In the startup script of the `vpn` container, add both DNS servers to the `resolv.conf` of the `vpn` container:

```sh
# vpn-container startup script:
echo "nameserver <remote dns server ip>" >> /etc/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver 127.0.0.11" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

To test this, log into the `vpn` container and try to `ping` a remote ip and the `db` container:

```sh
docker-compose run vpn /bin/bash
ping db  # should work
ping <some-ip-behind-the-vpn-tunnel>  # should also work
```

### Step 3: Expose the port

With `network_mode: "service:vpn"` on the `app` container, the `app` container cannot expose its ports to the host anymore as far as I understood. Instead, the `app` container and the `vpn` container appear as the same machine to the docker host, now. Therefore, one can expose the desired ports on the `vpn` container instead.

```
services:
  vpn:
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
```

The `app` (!) is then reachable through http://localhost:3001 on the docker host.

### Bringing all together: Final `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    depends_on:
      - db
      - vpn
    network_mode: "service:vpn"
  db:
    image: postgres
  vpn:
    build: ./vpn
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    command: >
      bash -c "echo 'nameserver <remote dns server ip>' >> /etc/resolv.conf
      && echo 'nameserver 127.0.0.11' >> /etc/resolv.conf
      && ..."
```

Comment: This works if you try to access the `app` from the host machine, what if you need to access it from another local machine ? it is not accessible then :-/

Comment: What about app accessing dB? Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, none of the solutions that I have found worked for me. I am using MacOs with an OpenVPN client. My use case was to have the following setup:

1. OpenVPN client running locally, providing access to private resources ( e.g Kafka )
2. Spinning up one service through docker-compose, that needs access to the private resources
3. Spinning up another service, through a separate docker-compose file, that again needs access to the private resources.

After a quick research on the "host" option, it turns out Docker’s host networking feature is not supported on MacOs — even though the docker run command doesn’t complain about it. The reason for that behaviour is that on MacOs, the docker daemon is running in a virtual machine, not natively on the host, which means it’s not connecting to host ports for your MacOs, but rather it’s connecting to host ports of the virtual machine.

[From the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/host/):
"The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server."

Here's also [the official GitHub thread](https://github.com/docker/roadmap/issues/238) about it.

However, the solution turned out to be straightforward.

First, I had to check my OpenVPN configuration. As per the picture, you can see it gave me a private IP address of 172.27.232.98.

[image]

After knowing this, I could set up the network's subnet and gateway, which my docker-compose files should use. The code is as follows:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: "no"
    networks:
      - vpn

networks:
  vpn:
    name: vpn
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.27.0.0/16
          gateway: 172.27.0.1
```

Some considerations:

1. It's beneficial to have this same code for each docker-compose file, so that every configuration uses the same network
2. Under the **networks: VPN: name** - it's necessary to have this name specified, otherwise docker would try to create a network, prefixed with the service name ( e.g app_vpn ), which will lead to creating a separate network. This generates a new problem - when you try to spin the other docker-compose, it will try to create a second network ( e.g app2_vpn ), but because of the overlapping config, it will possibly fail with the message "ERROR: Pool overlaps with other one on this address space".

Answer (score -1):

in my case it works.

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    network_mode: service:vpn
    depends_on:
      - db
      - vpn

  db:
    image: postgres
    network_mode: bridge

  vpn:
    network_mode: bridge
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    links:
      - db
```

but in this way, db don't communicate network with vpn. i wanna make whole network communicate with vpn. is there any way to db communicate with vpn? or postgres don't communicate with 'external network'? so i don't need to modify this docker-compose?(sorry for my ignorance but i don't know what postgres do exactly.) sorry for writing my problem here but i think we got similar case so i write here. sorry.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Stackoverflow works best if you post your question as a new question. From your new question, you can, of course, easily refer to this similar case by pasting a link. Good luck!

Comment: alright, but i gave you other method and i asked to you about db

Comment: No an answer. Read [ask]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32745444)