# Docker compose use host vpn

Tags: laravel, docker, networking, docker-compose, vpn

Im using the laravel example app with docker-compose.yml.

Also host is connected to VPN.

I want to access a resource behind VPN from docker container.

From docker service bash, im able to ping e.g. host IP or google.com, but not the IP from VPN resource, which i can ping from the host.

Its working if i use

```
network_mode: "host"
```

but then everything else is not working anymore.

I already tried to add extra_hosts config:

```
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
            - 'host.docker.vpn:192.168.41.23'
```

but no luck with that.

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
            - 'host.docker.vpn:192.168.41.23'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - redis
            - meilisearch
            - selenium
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-redis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    meilisearch:
        image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT:-7700}:7700'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-meilisearch:/meili_data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "wget", "--no-verbose", "--spider",  "http://localhost:7700/health"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
    selenium:
        image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
        volumes:
            - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-redis:
        driver: local
    sail-meilisearch:
        driver: local
```

Any idea how i can get this working?

Is it even possible to use bridge mode and also be able to use host vpn?

Help is appreciated and thank you!

Comment: Possibly a duplicate or similar problem to another question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69228372/docker-compose-route-traffic-through-vpn-except-for-connections-to-other-servic
I had this problem using MacOs with an OpenVPN client. Here is my answer to how I managed to solve the issue - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77688495/3161980